# aiohttp.ClientSession multipart/form-data

Tags: python, multipartform-data, aiohttp

I have a `curl` request:

```
# form data: id = 247, name = Test
curl '{HOST}' \
  -H 'content-type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundarywiBIWjWR7osAkgFI' \
  --data-raw $'------WebKitFormBoundarywiBIWjWR7osAkgFI\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="id"\r\n\r\n247\r\n' \
              '------WebKitFormBoundarywiBIWjWR7osAkgFI\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="name"\r\n\r\nTest\r\n' \
              '------WebKitFormBoundarywiBIWjWR7osAkgFI--\r\n'
```

To send the same request using `requests` + `requests_toolbelt`:

```
mp = MultipartEncoder(
   fields={'id': '247', 'name': 'Test'},
   boundary='----WebKitFormBoundarywiBIWjWR7osAkgFI'
)

answer = requests.post(
    '{HOST}',
    data=mp,
    headers={'Content-Type': mp.content_type })
```

But how can I send the same request using `aiohttp.ClientSession`? I have tried to use `MultipartWriter + set_content_disposition()` or `FormData + add_field()` but apparently I'm doing something wrong

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my case works fine:

```
boundary = '----WebKitFormBoundarywiBIWjWR7osAkgFI'
with aiohttp.MultipartWriter('form-data', boundary) as writer:
    # custom headers...
    # writer.headers['User-Agent'] = '...'

    data = {'id': '247', 'name': 'Test'}
    for key, value in data.items():
        part = writer.append(value, {'content-type': 'form-data'})
        part.set_content_disposition('form-data', name=key)

    async with session.post('{HOST}', data=writer) as resp:
        data = await resp.json()
```

JFYI: you can use `quote_fields=False` if you need to send form fields:

```
part = writer.append('VALUE', {'content-type': 'form-data'})
part.set_content_disposition('form-data', False, name='form_fields[field_0]')
```

Result:

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryGWdKpzFAElN34726\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="form_fields[field_0]"\r\n\r\nVALUE\r\n
```